# Add Active Class to active link on Custom Mobile Menu in Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hello this is my website https://yantranepal.com and when using it in mobile responsive view I have created a specific Mobile Menu/Navigation Bar that appears at the bottom/end of the page. I have achieved this using a plugin and everything works perfectly except I am unable to style the Active Link. For Example: When I click on home and I am redirected to Home Page, I want the Home Icon and Text to be highlighted in Blue for the time, however I am unable to do so. I have tried using the following CSS but I don't think *:active* works on Wordpress.

```
.icon_mobile_menu_item a:active {
color: #006d6f;
}
```

Can someone help on how can I do this? Is there a way I can add add Css Classes to active links using PHP or am I doing something wrong with CSS?

Comment: `:active` only works during the moment an element gets activated, for example as long as the user presses the mouse button down. It has nothing whatsoever to do with what page you are currently on. _"Is there a way I can add add Css Classes to active links"_ - depends on how it is getting generated, for now we don't know anything more but that you are doing it "using a plugin."

Comment: Your website is working well and the "active" class is already there and working fine , but not on `a`  but on the `div` with classes starting with `elementor-element` . The `----menu-active-color: #006d6f` is deciding the active menu color .

Comment: wp_nav adds classes to the li element such as current-menu-item so use that class to target current item. So would be like .current-menu-item a { color: #006d6f; }